# Return a distinct list of regions SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out how I can return a list of regions based off my SQL query.

My table consist of the following columns which I need to access, Region, longitude, latitude.

**Region** is located in the CafeAddress table and **longitude** and **latitude** of the cafes are under Cafe table.

My current SQL query:

```
Select Distinct r.Region, s.Longitude, s.Latitude 
From CafeAddress r , Cafe s
Order By Region
```

It currently returns a whole list of regions as the cafes are plotted with different lat and longs in one region hence why the cafes are repeated in my results.

```
Region      Longitude    Latitude
New York    -73.9904097 40.7036292
New York    174.764767  -36.850759
New York    174.764795  -36.852069
New York    174.765726  -36.846546
New York    174.765746  -36.849561
San Fran    174.6295402 -36.8566343
San Fran    174.777871  -36.870234
San Fran    174.778553  -36.852031
Tokyo       174.745957  -36.854023
Mumbai      174.74697   -36.8891
```

I thought doing a distinct would have limited it but because I'm returning the lat and long that no longer is helpful.

My expected outcome I want is something like this:

```
Region      Longitude    Latitude
New York    -73.9904097 40.7036292
San Fran    174.764767  -36.850759
Mumbai      174.764795  -36.852069
```

Just to have all the regions listed out but can't quite think of a way to just include it to just those.

If my SQL query just had

```
Select Distinct r.Region 
From CafeAddress r
Order By Region
```

It would return

```
New York    
San Fran    
Mumbai
```

Comment: You've used an old style cross join `CafeAddress r, Cafe s` which gives you every combination of records unless you add a filter. Instead use a *proper* `inner join` - one assumes you must have a foreign key relationship between the 2 tables.

Comment: yup they both have a cafeId

Comment: So join them properly - problem solved.

Comment: Don't you at least need `from CafeAddress r inner join Cafe s on S.CafeID = R.CafeId` to ensure you match an address to a cafe????

Comment: @DaleK Even when I do that I still get multiple outputs for each region

Comment: sure, but at least you will get a (random) lat/long from within the region (using the answer below) whereas now you just get a random lat/long from any region.

Comment: Is that really want you want? a random lat/long from with the region?

Comment: The purpose of this is to get a lat/long within the region I'm fine with it being random as long as it represents each region

Comment: How would I trim the list to only have the distinct regions show in my output? I'm looking to add this into my logic on my webapp in c#

Comment: @DaleK am I able to create an Id based off this each row? e.g. id: 1 , "Mumbai", 174, -36  or would I need to add a new column called id in the table?

Comment: I've already done it

Comment: I'm asking another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH region_list
     AS (SELECT r.Region, 
                s.Longitude, 
                s.Latitude, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Region
                ORDER BY s.Longitude DESC) AS row_no
         FROM CafeAddress r, 
              Cafe s)
     SELECT Region, 
            Longitude, 
            Latitude
     FROM region_list
     WHERE row_no = 1;
```

If you do not have a preference on which Longitude and Latitude you are using a [window function](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) in combination with a [common table expression](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) could be a good option. In the above code I am using a CTE with Row_Number() to number all of the regions in order of largest Longitude to smallest, which looks like this:

```
Region      Longitude    Latitude        row_no
New York    -73.9904097 40.7036292          6
New York    174.764767  -36.850759          4
New York    174.764795  -36.852069          5
New York    174.765726  -36.846546          2
New York    174.765746  -36.849561          1
San Fran    174.6295402 -36.8566343         3
San Fran    174.777871  -36.870234          2
San Fran    174.778553  -36.852031          1   
Tokyo       174.745957  -36.854023          1
Mumbai      174.74697   -36.8891            1
```

I then take that table I just built and select the first instance through "where row_no = 1". This gives me the following output:

```
Region      Longitude    Latitude        row_no
New York    174.765746  -36.849561          1
San Fran    174.778553  -36.852031          1   
Tokyo       174.745957  -36.854023          1
Mumbai      174.74697   -36.8891            1
```

Comment: I think you've missed the fact that OP is missing a join condition... which is the cause of the problem.

Comment: that seems to do the job!

Comment: @M.Palmer I noticed when I tried running that script It gave me all the locations but thye all had the same lat and long  which I found super weird?

Comment: was an accident :)

Comment: answers most of the question just had to add the inner join which you mentioned